# How to call stored proc from ASP.Net MVC stack via the ORM & return them in json?

Tags: asp.net, javascript, asp.net-mvc, json, stored-procedures

i'm a total newbie with asp.net mvc and here's my jam:

i have a 3 level list box which selection on box A shows options on box B and selection on box B will show the options for box C.

I'm trying to do the whole thing in asp.net MVC and what i see is that the nerd dinner tutorial uses the ORM method.

so i created a dbml to the database and drag the stored proc inside.
i create a datacontext object but i don't quite know how to connect the result from the stored proce which should be multiple rows of data and make it into a json.

so i can keep all the json data inside the html page and using jquery i could make the selection process faster.

i don't expect the data inside the three boxes to change so often thus i think this method should be quite viable.

### Questions:

1. So how do i get the stored proc part
   to return the data as json?
2. i've noticed [some tutorial online](http://www.ajaxprojects.com/ajax/tutorialdetails.php?itemid=399#start)
       that the json return result part is
       at the controller and not at the
       model end.
   Why is that?

Edit
FYI, i find what i mostly wanted to do [here.](http://blog.dervalp.com/2009/06/12/aspnet-mvc-c-linq-to-stored-procedure-with-dynamic-query-a-quick-phone-book-piece-of-cake/)
For the json part, i [referenced here](http://haacked.com/archive/2009/04/14/using-jquery-grid-with-asp.net-mvc.aspx).

Answer (score 2):

1. Return a JsonResult from your controller action.  You may need to coerce the result from your stored procedure into a C# class serializable to Json.
2. Json conversion should be done in the controller because it's not really part of the domain.  More a DTO in the MVVM (Model-View-ViewModel) style.

Comment: @rob_g can you give me some resources so i can understand the DTO in the MVVM style better? any good article to rec? thanks :)